# Blank space going off-screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to fix the following issue on this website: http://santanna.beutifi-website.com/

Notice that there is a blank space to the right as if the page has a wider width or margin, although after checking these features, I could not figure out what the problem is. It does not happen on mobile devices though.

I played with developer tools for quite a while and no luck, I was wondering if any of you might be able to see whats wrong...

Cheers!

Comment: I don't see the issue you're describing, I'm using Chrome with Windows 7. Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: I tried with Chrome and Firefox and can't see the issue

Comment: Guys, it doesn't show on 1920 and up. Size down the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started writing what @Matthew said but since you're using WordPress it's probably better to just overwrite the style. Try this:

```
.copyright{
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.copyright p{
  text-align:center !important;
}
```

Add that to custom styles of the theme if possible. Good luck!

Comment: Ha! should have looked at that, good catch. I didn't notice he was using WordPress.

Comment: I wish I could mark both of your answers, thank you so much Miro and Matthew!

Comment: Any time. Give @Matthew an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

The issue only shows when you make the screen size smaller. It is being caused by your css below:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 840px) (index):175
.copyright {
    margin-left: 25%; */
}
```

When I remove that it solved the problem.

If you want your text to be centered you can either remove the `text-left` class you have on that div and center it manually or you can add `text-align: center !important` to your copyright class after you remove the margin.

Edit:

Also you should not double up on the `.container` classes like you have below. Either use one or the other.

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-dark-gray footer-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row margin-three">
            <!-- copyright -->
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 copyright text-left letter-spacing-1 xs-text-center xs-margin-bottom-one light-gray-text2">
                <p align="left" style="font-size:11px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#939598;width: 100% !important;">Copyright © 2017. Built &amp; managed by <span style="color:#56c7cc;"><a href="https://beutifi.com/page/salons" target="_blank" "="">BEUTiFi.com</a></span> All rights reserved.</p>                    
            </div>
            <!-- end copyright -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the css in the .

the .container class item is set to a pixel width;